# Class inheritance problem in PHP

Tags: php, class, inheritance, properties, extends

Hi stackOverflow Family :),

I have a question, and I didt find the answer elsewhere. I try to explain my problem:
I have a class, and if I create an other class from it, from that child class I couldnt access the parent's properties.
I did something wrong?
I tried to copy my class variable to a local and try to give back that local one, but neither works of the following 3 way.

Here is my examples.
At first I simple create an object:

```
$test = new test();
```

And my two class is the following:

```
class test {

    public $testvar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->testvar = 1234568;
        echo ":) ".$this->testvar();
        $test2 = new test2();
}

    public function testvar() {
        echo "testvar() called > ";
        return $this->testvar;
    }
}
```

And test2:

```
class test2 extends test  {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "<br>:| this-> ".$this->testvar;
        echo "<br>:| parent:: ". parent::testvar();
        echo "<br>:| "; $this->testvar();
    }

}
```

May somebody have an idea?
Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misunderstood the inheritance concept. Instantiating `test2` in the constructor function of `test` is not inheritance.

The constructor of `test` was not called, therefore `testvar` was not set. Remove `$test2 = new test2();` from the constructor of `test`. Try:

```
class test {

    public $testvar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->testvar = 1234568;
        echo ":) ".$this->testvar();
}

    public function testvar() {
        echo "testvar() called > ";
        return $this->testvar;
    }
}

class test2 extends test  {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "<br>:| this-> ".$this->testvar;
        echo "<br>:| "; $this->testvar();
    }

}

$test2 = new test2();
```

See also the [PHP manual on constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) (and [classes](http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php) too).

Answer (score 0):

I guess, if you instanciate test2 in the constructor of test, it doesn't mean, that test 2 is instanciated in the context you've created, which means: the variables you set aren't available to test2 :)... I definetly shouldn't become a techear :-D

test2 should look something like:

```
class test2 extends test  {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo "<br>:| this-> ".$this->testvar;
    echo "<br>:| parent:: ". parent::testvar();
    echo "<br>:| "; $this->testvar();
  }
}
```

and the test-constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->testvar = 1234568;
    echo ":) ".$this->testvar();
}
```

and then you call new test2() outside of those classes!

Comment: I really misunderstood this. The test class works better, but where I have to instanciate test2? If I dont do it, the test2 object isnt will be.
But if I make it in the constructor, is become an ifinity loop.

Comment: @szatti1489 So you have the classes Test and Test2. Make a new php-file, e.g. testing.php, include Test.php and Test2.php (or whatever they're called) and then simply instanciate test2: $test2 = new $test2(); - when you open testing.php now, it should output '1234568' ;)

Comment: Yes, but my project is: test2 instatiated dinamically. Test is query data from DB, and instantiate from itself the child class which is needed by the table data. And I have to access the parent properties from this new class.

Comment: If I get you right: You pull DB data in the parent class (Test), but need Test2 to work with the data? You should never instanciate a parent class directly! The parent class is implicitly instanciated within the child-class by calling parent::__construct(); (not really just by calling it, but you get the idea...)  - then, all the properties you set in the constructor of the parent class can also be accessed from the child class.

Comment: Yes, something like you said. I query DB data from Test, and it reads the name Test2 from DB and instantiate an object $test2.
And from $test2 I like to use Test's properties.

I think, I have to create a third class, which instantiate Test, after that reads DB and instantiate Test2 if needed.

Comment: Now you got it ;) The way you were trying to approach it won't work, I guess. So yes, You've got to run the DB-query somewhere outside the Test-class and then only instanciate Test2. But if you think, the query belongs in the parent class anyway, you could put it in a static method, and then call it like $the_class = Test::RunQueryAndGetTheClass(); $test2 = new $the_class;

Comment: Yes I am! :) I coded it and create the third class but the next problem is comes up. The extended classes seems like doesnt inherits nothing, coz I cant access mysql connection with my global $conn variable. Problems grows...

Comment: Well, maybe you should reconsider your architecture then and get more familiar with OOP concepts :) For the fast way: Just search on YouTube for PHP OOP or something like that, I think that could be very helpful! Good luck ;)

Comment: Now I being familiar. ;) Thank you for your help!